# Display Map Property in Angular 8

Tags: angular, rest, spring-data-jpa

In my Angular 8 App I've got an entity `Mealplan` which has a map as a property, where the key is the `weekday` enumeration.

Now I want to display the map in my template like for example:

```
<li *ngFor="let meal of mealplan.mealsPerWeek">{{meal.weekday}}: {{meal.name}}</li>
```

for the Output:

```
- Monday: Burger
- Tuesday: Fish
etc.
```

This solution works for an Array, but not for a map.

**mealplan.ts**

```
export class Mealplan {
  id: number;
  week: number;
  mealsPerWeek: Map<Weekday, Meal>;
 }
```

**meal.ts**

```
export class Meal {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  art: string;
}
```

**weekday.ts**

```
export enum Weekday {
  Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
}
```

The JSON from my REST API looks like this:

```
{
id: 1,
week: 10,
mealsPerWeek: {
  Thursday: {
   id: 5,
   name: "Lasagne",
   price: 4.5,
   art: "with Meat"
   },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
<div *ngFor="let meal of mealplan.mealsPerWeek | keyvalue">
    {{meal.key}}: {{meal.value.name}}
</div>
```

Output:

```
Tuesday: Salad
Thursday: Lasagne
Friday: Fish
Wednesday: Burger
Monday: Soup
```

Edit:

I realised, that the KeyValuePipe sort key strings in alphabetical order. To prevent this, you can write `| keyvalue : returnZero` in the template

and in  typescript you write a simple function that returns 0.

```
returnZero(): number {
 return 0;
}
```